# Creating User Groups in PHP (Using multi-select dropdown)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, mysqli

I am using the JQuery Multi-select dropdown plugin ([example here](http://jsfiddle.net/StephenEdmondson/TR49m/4/)) to assign users to users groups in bulk. If I was doing this individually it would be straight forward, but I'm pretty weak when it comes to understanding 'bulk actions' in PHP, or any language for that matter.

This is my database structure:

```
|--------|             |-----------------|            |-------|
| Groups | ------- 1.* | GroupMembership | *.1------- | Users |
|--------|             |-----------------|            |-------|
```

Basically, `Group_ID` in `Groups`, `User_ID` in `Users` and both in `GroupMembership`, that's pretty much how I'm setting the simple relation.

However, how, in PHP & MySQLi, can I collect the multiple values from a single input field as an array and process them as individual inserts into `GroupMembership`?

Imagine you're looking at a list of user groups, and next to each group name you have a dropdown to select multiple users. The value of `$_POST['Group_ID']` will contain multiple `User_ID` values eg: `21, 22, 34, 55, 64, 75, 87, 96`. How can I take each of these user IDs and insert a record into GroupMembership for each user?

Visualising the solution, I need to loop through something like the code below for each value in the $_POST array?

```
$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO GroupMembership (Group_ID, User_ID) VALUES (?, ?)");
//the rest of the prepared stmt code.
```

I'm probably over-thinking this but as an early stage student I'm going to let myself off and pray for someone to share their wisdom :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as an early stage student you HAVE to split the task into stages. Client stage and server stage. And work on them separately

Comment: My client stage is fine, I have the interface working perfectly, if that's what you're referring to? This question is focussed on how to loop through MySQLi insert queries using the values from an array?

Comment: you cannot loop through queries. you rather loop through input data. and this input data is what you get from client. So - either you have it or you *don't* have the interface working perfectly

Comment: How would you suggest I post the data from the multiselect, if not in the format of an array consisting of comma separated values?

Comment: you can have already an array if name your input as 'input[]'. But comma separated is okay. if you need only to know how to split it, then explode() is what you need

Comment: I'll explore this and post back, thanks for your time!

Comment: You're a legend, it was `[]` in the fields name to construct an array that I needed, I've never seen this done before... THANKS!